# C++ MFC CObject derived class abstract?

Tags: c++, mfc

Is it possible to have a base class non-abstract and the derived class from this base as 
an abstract?
(in Cpp)

I'm in MFC App and I am inheriting from CObject,
i wonder if my class can be abstract or not..

thanks.

Comment: Sure, [that's possible](https://godbolt.org/z/yA6VwZ). Still, what [problem](http://xyproblem.info) are you trying to solve?

Comment: MFC itself derives *many* classes from `CObject` that are abstract. For example: `CView` has `virtual void OnDraw(CDC* pDC) = 0;`.

Answer (score 0):

YES, just you should have **at least one virtual function**
here an example :

```
class CShape : public CObject
{
public:
virtual CPoint GetCenterPoint() = 0;
};


class CCircle : public CShape
{
public: 
CPoint GetCenterPoint() override;
};
```